# R : Creating new dataframe by combining two dataframe by common rows

Tags: r, merge, dataframe

I  have two data frames of cities with population and location , population only have 50 cities while location have 100.

Step 1. select cities from location data to match **"city_name"** in population data.

step 2. joining the location data with population data for only 50 cities of cities.population. I have tried merge but couldn't got through.

result

```
city_name, population, latitude, longitude 
 Anantapur    7,677,018,  14.70      77.59
```

cities.population

```
Rank city_name State.Territory Population..2011..14. Population..2001..15.
1        Mumbai     Maharashtra            18,394,912            16,434,386
2         Delhi           Delhi            16,349,831            13,850,507
3       Kolkata     West Bengal            14,057,991            13,205,697
4       Chennai      Tamil Nadu             8,653,521             6,560,242
5     Bangalore       Karnataka             8,520,435             5,701,446
6      Anantapur      Telangana             7,677,018             5,742,036
```

cities_location

```
 X   city_name latitude longitude                         state
 1  Port Blair  11.67 N   92.76 E  Andaman and Nicobar Islands)
 2    Adilabad  19.68 N   78.53 E               Andhra Pradesh)
 3       Adoni  15.63 N   77.28 E               Andhra Pradesh)
 4       Alwal  17.50 N   78.54 E               Andhra Pradesh)
 5  Anakapalle  17.69 N   83.00 E               Andhra Pradesh)
 6   Anantapur  14.70 N   77.59 E               Andhra Pradesh)
```

Comment: Sounds like `merge` will get you what you want if used properly. Can you include what you tried with `merge`?

Comment: `merge(cities.population, cities.location, all.x = TRUE)`

Comment: merge(ic,cc,by.x=c('city_name'),by.y=c('city_name'))

Comment: ic = cities_location, cc = cities_population

Comment: Is there a way where I can just match rownames from a vector to select only those rows. I tried subset condition plus dplyr select, but none seems to work

Comment: Does the `merge` code I posted in a comment not work for you? You can subset by rows like `cc[cc$city_name %in$ ic$city_name, ]` using the abbreviations you mentioned.

Comment: Thanks Alex, the merge is giving NA in the merge section. I searched it with hand in excel just to be sure that the data is there. I guess I have to sleep over it.

Comment: In that case, try it with `all.x = TRUE, all.y = FALSE`.

Answer (score 0):

```
dplyr::inner_join(cities.population, cities_location)
```

you can be more careful by specifying `by='city_name'`